# using external lib in angular-cli application

Tags: javascript, angular-cli

I would like to add an axternal javascript library I created. How can I do it? 
Let's say I have a file, `converter.js`

that file looks like that:

```
module.export = {
    myFunc: a=>a
}
```

and I copy it in `./lib` folder

Then in `.angular-cli.json` I add this entry into app:
`"scripts": ["../lib/converter.js"]`,

I can see in the source of html file the javascript file containing my file. Good.

But I don't understand how to use myFunc for example in app.component.ts...

Like doc said

> Once you import a library via the scripts array, you should not import
>   it via a import statement in your TypeScript code (e.g. import * as $
>   from 'jquery';). If you do that, you'll end up with two different
>   copies of the library: one imported as a global library, and one
>   imported as a module.

...

> If the global library you need to use does not have global typings,
>   you can also declare them manually in src/typings.d.ts as any:
>
> declare var libraryName: any;

And I did: `declare var myFunc: any` in src/typings.d.ts

Nut nothing: trying to call myFunc (as global) but it was undefined.

Thank you

Comment: You mean you dont know how to use that function in .ts files?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib) for more information.

Comment: @vicbyte yes, at the end I would like to use a javascript function in .ts file.

Comment: Please who downgrade should write a reason. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your declaration is correct, although I would prefer `declare var myFunc: (any) => any;`. I see that you use `module.export` in your library, may be for using it server-side in node.js. That's the syntax used by the SystemJS module loader. It was used in old Angular tutorials. Since Angular CLI switched to Webpack as a module loader, we don't need it anymore.

Try to write your function as following:

```
var myFunc = function (a) {
  return a;
}
```

You have chosen to add your script to the `"scripts"` array in .angular-cli.json. That apparently works. But I don't like declaring functions on the global scope. There probably must be a better way of importing a library. Try to use the `import` way instead as R. Richards suggested.